# primefaces chart export as image, the title is not auto new line

Tags: charts, primefaces, jqplot

The chart is displayed good, and the title has two rows. But after export as the image to the dialog, it changed to be one line. 
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grHMk.png)

Comment: Provide versioninfo PF one and by checking the PF source also the jqplot one. And also search the jpplot forum please as this most likely is not something that PF can solve

Comment: I use primefaces 6.0. And I found if i use the jquery to export as image , it is the same problem. var imgData = $('#yearchart').jqplotToImageStr({}); 
                    var imgElem = $('<img/>').attr('src',imgData);
                    $('#yearoutput').empty().append(imgElem);
                    PF('yeardlg').show();

Comment: Your screenshot link is not working, plus please include some code in the question.